# Acessing HttpContext from request-scoped class

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I have a class, inherited from **IDependency**. What is the best way to access HttpContext from my class? I want to access it as early a possible, once HttpContext becomes available.

I tried to add dependency injection for **IWorkContextAccessor** to my class, and access it from the constructor, but **GetContext()** returns **null** then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current HttpContext is available via **IWorkContextAccessor** object **after** the IoC container objects get created, so you won't be able to access those in the constructor. The best way is to access the context object when you want to use it - not earlier - especially **not** inside the constructor, as constructors get called very early by the Autofac.

You can also inject **IOrchardServices** object *(let's call it "services")* and then use the **services.WorkContext.HttpContext** object.

Could you provide some greater detail at what you want to achieve? Why would you want to access that so early? Couldn't this be rewritten so the context object will be used later (eg. in some method call)?

HTH

Comment: Let me spread some light on what I`m trying to made. I`m customizing the **DefaultCultureManager** class. The intention is to move culture selection logic from the **GetCurrentCulture** method to another private method, that will be called only once when an **HttpContext** becomes available. The reason is because **GetCurrentCulture** method is being called too often.

I looked for some kind of component, that aggregates application-level events, like **BeginRequest**, and which can be accessed from the **DefaultCultureManager**, but didn`t find anything.

Comment: So you'd like to minimize the performance impact of retrieving the current culture each time the **GetCurrentCulture** method gets called? I guess the best option (in terms of clarity and best-practice) would be to use caching (via **ICacheManager**). The first time the method gets called the cache would be created and retrieved in subsequent calls. Afaik there's no easy way to hook up into "lifecycle" events, but I guess the Team will work on that (necessity of such feature was mentioned a couple of times).